# Time in Ubuntu 16.04 not updating from internet

Tags: time

I am new to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The time on my machine is not updating from internet. I have changed the CMOS battery and also installed `ntp` and `ntpdate` and ran `sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com`. But none of these worked for me.

Running below command temporarily updates the time

```
sudo date -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z"
```

Is there any other way to update my system time? I don't want to set it manually every session.

Comment: Please mark the answer if it fixed your problem

Comment: @Efren No it didn't, I ended up pasting the above command in a script which runs  everytime the machine starts

Comment: That's strange, so what was the timsyncd service status?

Comment: Sorry I no longer remember,  shortly after this I was assigned a new windows machine

Answer (score 9):

Ubuntu 16.04 works with [timedatectl / timesyncd](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html)

Check the **timseyncd** service is ok: `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd`

Possibly something is [blocking the service](https://superuser.com/a/943460/221203) (eg: ntpd installed), so it avoids syncing to avoid conflicts.

Another possibility is that you may be running a VirtualBox and you may see an error like:

```
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d
           └─disable-with-time-daemon.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Mon 2018-02-12 17:40:50 AEDT; 1min 31s ago
           ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/VBoxService was not met
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
```

This was a solution for this case: `sudo VBoxService --timesync-set-start`. 
Inspired from [this issue](https://github.com/lcreid/rails-5-jade/issues/15) with a similar error

Answer (score 3):

In my case what I did is comment the line `ConditionFileIsExecutable=!/usr/sbin/VBoxService` in file `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d/disable-with-time-daemon.conf` and then:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start systemd-timesyncd
```

All started to work again.